# Redshift COPY command ignores table default values if column list not provided

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, copy, amazon-redshift

I have a table, `myTable` which has some columns with default values.

I have a json file, `jsonfile.json` with data for that table which doesn't have a value for every field in the table.

When I attempt to perform a copy like this:

```
COPY myTable
from 's3://bucket/jsonfile.json' 
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/redshift-role'
FORMAT AS JSON 'auto'
GZIP
```

The missing fields from the file should let the table set its default values upon copy, but instead the values are set to null or empty.

If instead I perform a copy like this:

```
COPY myTable(a, b, c)  --doesn't even have to have the full column list
from 's3://bucket/jsonfile.json' 
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/redshift-role'
FORMAT AS JSON 'auto'
GZIP
```

Then the columns in the table with default values will be set to their defaults.

I have searched around and found nothing describing this, or at least that I understood to be this scenario.

Anyone see this before?

Answer (score 0):

You should post some example data to make things clearer.  It is important to remember that for text that empty strings and NULL are different.  The empty string is a value where NULL is not and default values are only assigned if no value is given for the column.  So in your data are the fields without data in your source files as empty strings?  I expect so but showing example data would clarify.  There is an option to COPY of JSON files that will map the empty string to NULL - "EMPTYASNULL".  If I'm correct with my assumptions this could fix your issue.